# Scheduling Policy and processes

Tags: awk, scheduling, policy, ps

I want to print  for all my running processes and not just a specific one the result of this command :

```
chrt -p PID
```

i have tried this but didn't work :

```
x=$(ps -e | awk '{print $1}')`
chrt -p x
```

I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use a looping construct to perform task for all running processes:-

```
ps -eo pid | while read pid; do print "chrt -p $pid"; done
```

Remove the `print` and rerun, if output looks good.

Comment: The script I posted without `print` should generate this out:- `ps -eo pid | while read pid; do chrt -p $pid; done`

Comment: You can redirect stderr: `chrt -p $pid 2> /dev/null`